# How do I enter a null value in the thymeleaf field of an html page?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm making an input page using thymeleaf:

**insertText.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handing Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/insertText}" th:object="${text}" method="post">
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${text.id}" />
    <p th:text="'parent_id' + ${text.parent_id} ?: 'original'" />
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${text.name}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${text.operation}" />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the parent_it field I want to enter null if it is the original text but I get an error:

```
Field error in object 'textTable' on field 'parent_id': rejected value [null]; 
codes [typeMismatch.textTable.parent_id,typeMismatch.parent_id,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [textTable.parent_id,parent_id]; arguments []; default message [parent_id]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'parent_id'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"]]
```

Although in the post page I added zero value processing:

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Getting Started: Handing Form Submission</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${text.id}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${text?.parent_id}" />
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${text.name}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${text.operation}" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe there is a way to make this possible?

My entity
**textTablt**

```
package com.example.HiberTest.Entities;


@Entity
@Table(name = "textTable")
public class textTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parent_id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=1, max=128)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=1, max=128)
    @Column(name = "operation")
    private String operation;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public void setParent_id(Integer parent_id) {
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("id = %o" +
                        ", parent_id = %o, " +
                        "name = %s, operation = %s ",
                id,parent_id,name,operation);
    }
}
```

My conroller:

```
package com.example.HiberTest.Controller;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class TextController {

    @Autowired
    daoRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/insertText")
    public String insertText(Model model){
        //List<textTable> list =dao.findAll();
        //model.addAttribute("texts",list);
        model.addAttribute("text", new textTable());
        return "insertText";
    }

    @PostMapping("/insertText")
    public String getAllText(@ModelAttribute textTable texts, Model model){
        //List<textTable> list =dao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("text", texts);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

I would be glad of help to figure out how to enter a null value so that it is processed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your variable parent_id in class textTable is of type Integer but you are trying to insert string in it. you are trying to append integer id in string 'parent_id' and then store in Database that's why you are getting error.

Comment: But id is converted normally, I tried to change text to value, but the result is the same, apparently it can't be done